# java 8 lambda with previous value

Tags: java, lambda

How do I / Can I change the following method to use streams?

In the imperative programming style, I store the previous value of city, and had to use that to get the next value see `e.getOther()` (Don't ask me why).

The focus of the question is: How to achieve the same output with streams / lambda?

```
private <V extends City, E extends WeightedEdge<V>> void printWeightedEdgePath(List<E> pathList, V srcVertex, V destVertex) {
    PrintVisitor printVisitor = new PrintVisitor();
    if (!pathList.isEmpty()) {
        V atThisCity = srcVertex;
        System.out.printf("%s to %s:  %s", srcVertex, destVertex, srcVertex);
        pathList.stream().forEach(edge -> { // stream way - error
            printVisitor.accept(edge);
            System.out.printf(" --%2.2f-->", e.weight());
            atThisCity = e.getOther(atThisCity); // variable must be final
            printVisitor.accept(atThisCity);
        });
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s to %s:  not connected\n", srcVertex, destVertex);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Edit: Thanks to @Bohemian trick - cheating java out of final using array of obj.

```
private <V extends City, E extends Edge<V>> void printEdgePath(List<E> pathList, V srcVertex, V destVertex) {
    PrintVisitor printVisitor = new PrintVisitor();
    if (!pathList.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex [] atThisCity = new Vertex[]{srcVertex};
        System.out.printf("%s to %s:  %s", srcVertex, destVertex, srcVertex);
        pathList.stream().forEach(edge -> {
            printVisitor.accept(edge);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            V nextCity = edge.getOther((V)atThisCity[0]);
            atThisCity[0] = nextCity;
            printVisitor.accept(atThisCity[0]);
        });
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s to %s:  not connected\n", srcVertex, destVertex);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I don't think lambdas are the right choice for this one - your previous city reference ends up as state within your routine. You can create an implementation of Consumer where you could have a City instance variable - the forEach call can take a reference to a Consumer interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a work around for circumventing the "effectively final" requirement:

If you need to modify a value in a lambda, use an array. While the *array* is final, its contents may be mutated. ie:

```
Object[] array = new Object[1];
someStream.forEach(o -> {processPreviousAndCurrent(array[0], o); array[0] = o;});
```

In this trivial example, the array holds the previous value.

In your example, do this:

```
 private <V extends City, E extends WeightedEdge<V>> void printWeightedEdgePath(List<E> pathList, V srcVertex, V destVertex) {
    PrintVisitor printVisitor = new PrintVisitor();
    if (!pathList.isEmpty()) {
        Object[] atThisCity = new Object[]{srcVertex};
        System.out.printf("%s to %s:  %s", srcVertex, destVertex, srcVertex);
        pathList.stream().forEach(edge -> {
            printVisitor.accept(edge);
            System.out.printf(" --%2.2f-->", e.weight());
            atThisCity[0] = e.getOther((V)atThisCity[0]);
            printVisitor.accept(atThisCity);
        });
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s to %s:  not connected\n", srcVertex, destVertex);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```